# Link user to the app store-there are 2 options

Tags: objective-c

I know 2 options how to do that ,

First ,the one apple give you at the docs :

```
NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id284417350?mt=8";
```

second,another one that i could find here ,

```
NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=666666666";
```

I need 2 links, one that direct user to **update**, and one that direct user to **rate** the app .

What are the relevant links to each scenario ,and what my links do ?
I believe the second is the one for review ?

Thanks .

Comment: "what my links do?" Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 1):

First one of for update/link to app (another app or yours, depending on id, ofc) and the second one is to rate and/or add a review to your app (the user can do both or just one of them).

And yea, why didn't you just test it? Make a dummy button and just click and check until is ok.